# How to add a new column to a Delta Lake table?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I'm trying to add a new column to data stored as a Delta Table in Azure Blob Storage. Most of the actions being done on the data are upserts, with many updates and few new inserts. My code to write data currently looks like this:

```
DeltaTable.forPath(spark, deltaPath)
      .as("dest_table")
      .merge(myDF.as("source_table"),
             "dest_table.id = source_table.id")
      .whenNotMatched()
      .insertAll()
      .whenMatched(upsertCond)
      .updateExpr(upsertStat)
      .execute()
```

From [these docs](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html#automatic-schema-evolution), it looks like Delta Lake supports adding new columns on `insertAll()` and `updateAll()` calls only. However, I'm updating only when certain conditions are met and want the new column added to all the existing data (with a default value of `null`).

I've come up with a solution that seems extremely clunky and am wondering if there's a more elegant approach. Here's my current proposed solution:

```
// Read in existing data
val myData = spark.read.format("delta").load(deltaPath)
// Register table with Hive metastore
myData.write.format("delta").saveAsTable("input_data")

// Add new column
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE input_data ADD COLUMNS (new_col string)")

// Save as DataFrame and overwrite data on disk
val sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM input_data")
sqlDF.write.format("delta").option("mergeSchema", "true").mode("overwrite").save(deltaPath)
```

Comment: Use jdbc not spark. This is not for that.

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Alter your delta table first and then you do your merge operation:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

spark.read.format("delta").load('/mnt/delta/cov')\
  .withColumn("Recovered", lit(''))\
  .write\
  .format("delta")\
  .mode("overwrite")\
  .option("overwriteSchema", "true")\
  .save('/mnt/delta/cov')
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I ended up doing. However, this also works (at least in Databricks on Azure): 

ALTER TABLE delta.`wasbs://my-table@azureaccount.blob.core.windows.net/` ADD COLUMNS (mycol STRING);

Comment: But in this way...we are not doing schema Evolution :-(

Comment: that's not a merge operation, that's an overwrite operation. Have a look at the delta docs on how to merge:

https://docs.delta.io/0.4.0/api/python/index.html

Comment: you're not using schema evolution, are you loading a rewriting the data? Also how does this effect the history?

Comment: overwrite operation creates a full copy of history to add a blank column, which is not really efficient

Answer (score 13):

New columns can also be added with SQL commands as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE dbName.TableName ADD COLUMNS (newColumnName dataType)

UPDATE dbName.TableName SET newColumnName = val;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach that worked for me using scala

Having a delta table, named `original_table`, which path is:

```
val path_to_delta = "/mnt/my/path"
```

This table currently has got 1M records with the following schema: `pk`, `field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4`

I want to add a new field, named `new_field`, to the existing schema without loosing the data already stored in `original_table`.

So I first created a dummy record with a simple schema containing just `pk` and `newfield`

```
case class new_schema(
  pk: String,
  newfield: String
)
```

I created a dummy record using that schema:

```
import spark.implicits._
val dummy_record = Seq(new new_schema("delete_later", null)).toDF
```

I inserted this new record (the existing 1M records will have `newfield` populated as null). I also removed this dummy record from the original table:

```
dummy_record
  .write
  .format("delta")
  .option("mergeSchema", "true")
  .mode("append")
  .save(path_to_delta )

val original_dt : DeltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, path_to_delta )
original_dt .delete("pk = 'delete_later'")
```

Now the original table will have 6 fields: `pk`, `field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4` and `newfield`

Finally I upsert the `newfield` values in the corresponding 1M records using `pk` as join key

```
val df_with_new_field = // You bring new data from somewhere...

original_dt 
  .as("original")
  .merge(
    df_with_new_field .as("new"),
    "original.pk = new.pk")
  .whenMatched
  .update( Map(
    "newfield" -> col("new.newfield")
    ))
  .execute()
```

https://www.databricks.com/blog/2019/09/24/diving-into-delta-lake-schema-enforcement-evolution.html

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using the merge statement?

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/merge-into.html

Comment: when I test merge into will no add the new column