# How to add Delta Lake generated column using SQL to an existing table?

Tags: sql, databricks, delta-lake

Trying to add a Delta Lake generated column using SQL, and then partition by it. I am following the [Databricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/generated-columns.html) which provide the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE events(
eventId BIGINT,
data STRING,
eventType STRING,
eventTime TIMESTAMP,
eventDate date GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CAST(eventTime AS DATE))
)
PARTITIONED BY (eventType, eventDate)
```

My question is: how can I alter this code for an existing table? What I want to accomplish is to do something like `GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CAST(eventTime AS DATE))` to an existing table and then partition by this generated column.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63528754/how-to-add-a-new-column-to-a-delta-lake-table) question is related, but does not focus on using GENERATED.

Comment: i don't follow, you need additional columns? or you want to ALTER TABLE

Comment: I want to generate a new column to an existing table using the technique provided in the Databricks doc.

Comment: Databricks doesn't support generated on an alter table, so why not make a new table and copy all data

Comment: I don't care about ALTER TABLE, I just want to generate a new column using DATE() and HOUR() functions, likely involving CAST(), but I'm not sure.

Comment: the generated column feature is only in  a preview and so will still take some time till it reaches production status

Comment: That doesn't matter for my use case.

Comment: @nbk - You say *"Databricks doesn't support generated on an alter table"* above, could you link some documentation regarding the limits of generated columns?  The official databricks docs I can find are very sparse on the subject.

Comment: you have to see the documentation https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-alter-table.html it shows you all supported commands if there is no generated in the documentation , it is not supported